# migration from .NET1.1 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I am currently using .NET 1.1 but my client wants to move application from .NET 1.1 to .NET3.5.
So client wants know how they will be benifited if migrate from 1.1 to 3.5.

What are the benifits of 3.5 over 1.1 for clients who is using that application?

Comment: The benefits are mostly for the developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With every version upgrade in .NET there's a bunch of new features these features might be language / compiler enhancements which are not visually regocnizable by the end user.

However these features makes it easier for the developer to create solid and manageable applications, then one might wonder; What is really benefiting the end user?

If it is easier for you to create readable code that is much easier to test and quality ensure, then it will most likely benefit the end user.

It's also become much easier to create trivial things in later .NET versions which will save you some development time which benefits the client of yours.

From a developers perspective there are a handfull of reasons why you should use .NET 2.0+ instead of 1.1 and all these reasons will in the end most likely give you a more trustworthy application which is to more value for your client.

Answer (score 0):

it's a higher number? :-)

no serious, i think as long as you don't implement new features, the upgrade vom 1.1 to 3.5 will bring him few benefits. some security updates are included, and he will can deploy also asp.net-mvc applications on the same server.

but i don't see any great advantages for clients.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from 1.1 to 2.0 (and higher) is a *must*.

The most obvious benefit I see on top of my head, without much thinking is the use of generics which was introduced by the CLR 2.

And don't forget support for 1.1 has simply **ended**, see here: [.NET 1.1 mainstream support ended in 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/Default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=.NET+Framework)

So the question would better be "what are the risks"? Here is a document on this subject: [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 and 2.0 Compatibility.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994381.aspx)